# why findViewById return null in android-section-list

Tags: android, inheritance, layout, android-activity, classloader

[Here is the original code](https://code.google.com/p/android-section-list/)

I have created in src root a `testing` package end there a `SectionListActivityExtended`

Is is just  a plain alias, but in different package:

```
package testing;

import pl.polidea.sectionedlist.SectionListActivity;

public class SectionListActivityExtended extends SectionListActivity{

}
```

Modified the AndroidManifest.xml part:

```
   <activity
        android:name="testing.SectionListActivityExtended"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/SectionListViewTheme" >
```

and modified the SectionListActivity:

```
@Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        arrayAdapter = new StandardArrayAdapter(this, R.id.example_text_view, exampleArray);
        sectionAdapter = new SectionListAdapter(getLayoutInflater(), arrayAdapter);
        String className = SectionListActivity.class.getPackage().getName();//className: pl.polidea.sectionedlist
        System.out.println("className: "+className);//className: pl.polidea.sectionedlist
        listView = (SectionListView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("section_list_view", "id", className));
        listView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
    }
```

Tested and is working, it write out the package name with class name label, not important now.

I have created my working application ( which has a lot of styles and definitions under NDA ) I have copied the source code with required files to my project in hope  I will get working. Modified the `SectionListActivity` and is called from an extended class, similar as above: different root package.

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        arrayAdapter = new StandardArrayAdapter(this, R.id.example_text_view, exampleArray);
        sectionAdapter = new SectionListAdapter(getLayoutInflater(), arrayAdapter);

//      FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.listView);
//      if (frameLayout == null) {
//          Log.e("tag", "got frameLayout");
//      } else {
//
//          Log.e("tag", "frameLayout is NULL");
//      }

        String packageName = SectionListActivity.class.getPackage().getName();//pl.polidea.sectionedlist
        System.out.println("packageName: " + packageName);
        listView = (SectionListView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("section_list_view", "id", packageName));
        if (listView != null) {
            listView.setAdapter(sectionAdapter);
        } else {
            Log.e(packageName, "Can't load section_list_view ");
        }
    }
```

Both `frameLayout` and `listView` are null.

From other posts the major cause is because they don't passing the attrs to super, but this part of the code in untouched:

```
public SectionListView(final Context context, final AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    commonInitialisation();
}
```

Maybe at styling it isn't merged something, but don't know how to trace or maybe I miss something and didn't knew yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

DO this way

```
listView = (SectionListView) findViewById(getResources().getIdentifier("section_list_view", "id", getPackageName()));
```

Comment: couldn't  see a reason for changes, but I have tried. Now the package name is at the calling package name. With this not  worked even on the original code, thats why needed to change that part